# python program give error(fraction knapsack problem)

Tags: python, algorithm, greedy

fraction knapsack problem with python it gives an error when i'm running the code, is the split function is not working for the integer values.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Akshay/Desktop/python/kapsack_problem.py", line 49, in <module>
    .format(n)).split()
  File "<string>", line 1
    60 100 120
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here is the source code of a Python program to solve the fractional knapsack problem using greedy algorithm. what i'm doing wrong please tell me.
thanks in advance.

```
def fractional_knapsack(value, weight, capacity):

    index = list(range(len(value)))
    # contains ratios of values to weight
    ratio = [v/w for v, w in zip(value, weight)]
    # index is sorted according to value-to-weight ratio in decreasing order
    index.sort(key=lambda i: ratio[i], reverse=True)

    max_value = 0
    fractions = [0]*len(value)
    for i in index:
        if weight[i] <= capacity:
            fractions[i] = 1
            max_value += value[i]
            capacity -= weight[i]
        else:
            fractions[i] = capacity/weight[i]
            max_value += value[i]*capacity/weight[i]
            break

    return max_value, fractions


n = int(input('Enter number of items: '))
value = input('Enter the values of the {} item(s) in order: '
              .format(n)).split()
value = [int(v) for v in value]
weight = input('Enter the positive weights of the {} item(s) in order: '
               .format(n)).split()
weight = [int(w) for w in weight]
capacity = int(input('Enter maximum weight: '))

max_value, fractions = fractional_knapsack(value, weight, capacity)
print('The maximum value of items that can be carried:', max_value)
print('The fractions in which the items should be taken:', fractions)
```

Comment: You code runs fine on my machine. I run it, enter some values and it returns me some answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you try to run this code with a `Python 2.x` interpreter, while your code is written in `Python 3`. In order to be able to run it, you need to check that `Python 3` is installed on your machine (see [here](https://www.python.org/) for installations instructions).
To run it, run

```
python3 my_script.py
```

in a terminal.
Another possiblity is to paste

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

at the top of your python script. Then if you make the file executable (by running `chmod +x myscript.py` on ubuntu for instance), you can then run it simply with

```
./my_script.py
```